# Universal linking not working

Tags: deep-linking, entitlements, ios-universal-links

I'm done how to  universal linking setup  but in entitlements file app target had `unselected` and disable to select. I didn't understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> select your "*.entitlements" file

This should add the tick mark in the target and fix your issue.

Comment: no ,it still the same.it doesn't work.it opens only the app,no redirection.

Comment: @AbdulNouzil what redirection are you talking about if I may ask?